# How to get this sound

Tags: replication, fl-studio

How to get this vibrating sound in this song

? I am using FL Studio, and I know that this vibrato can be made with pitch changing but from what sound to start? Is this some kind of rhode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can create this sound.

So the fundamental sound is a simple sine wave with another sine oscillator either an octave above or below (or a combination both) the fundamental. To achieve the atonal chord present in this track, you have two options:

Apply a frequency shifter to the sine waves or use a type of atonal/micro-tonal musical scale.

I recommend using a frequency shifter simply because you could get your hands on one pretty easily. Melda Production's frequency shifter is actually one of the best, free frequency shifters out there because it doesn't alter the pitch of the input sound like many do.